# If 10% of a substance decays in 10 years, what is the half-life of the substance?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A radioactive substance decays at a rate proportional to the amount present. If 10% of such a substance decays in 10 years, what is the half-life of the substance?

Answer (score 2):

In one decade, 90% of the stuff will remain. In two decades, 81% ($.9\times.9$) of the stuff will remain. In three decades, 72.9% of it will still be there ($.9^3$). To find the half-life, you need to solve the following equation: $$\mathord{.}9^x=\mathord{.}5,$$ where $x$ is the number of decades over which half of the stuff decays. Take logarithms of both sides: $$ x\times(\ln .9)=\ln.5\Longleftrightarrow x=\frac{\ln .5}{\ln .9}\approx6.5788.$$ Therefore, the half-life is a little less than 66 years.

Answer (score 0):

It decays exponentially, so the amount $x$ after $t$ years is given by $x(t)=x_0e^{-kt}$ for some constant $k$. You know that $x(10)=0.9x_0$, so $e^{-10k}=0.9$. Take the natural log and solve for $k$, then set $e^{-kt}=0.5$ and solve for $t$ to get the half-life.